# SQL Server : combine query result to one row

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I want to format the query like this. is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Typically, this kind of thing is handled in the client code or reporting tool.

Comment: Also, if you want an actual answer, you'll remove the images and copy/paste your code and sample data into the questions, and then use the code formatting button on the editing toolbar. Few people here are willing to deal with images. They're much harder for us to read, and forces us to retype all of your table names into our answer, rather than starting from what you have.

Comment: Please avoid using images for code and / or desired results.

Answer (score 1):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(CASE WHEN CHECKTYPE = 'I' AND TIMETYPE = 'AM' THEN FORMAT(CHECKTIME, N'HH:mm') END) [AM-IN],
  MAX(CASE WHEN CHECKTYPE = 'O' AND TIMETYPE = 'AM' THEN FORMAT(CHECKTIME, N'HH:mm') END) [AM-OUT],
  MAX(CASE WHEN CHECKTYPE = 'I' AND TIMETYPE = 'PM' THEN FORMAT(CHECKTIME, N'HH:mm') END) [PM-IN],
  MAX(CASE WHEN CHECKTYPE = 'O' AND TIMETYPE = 'PM' THEN FORMAT(CHECKTIME, N'HH:mm') END) [PM-OUT]
FROM [dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
WHERE [USERID] = N'21477' AND [CHECKTIME] BETWEEN N'2020-02-3 00:00:00' AND N'2020-02-4 00:00:00'
GROUP BY [USERID]
```